# Probability for packet length and bit error rate

Tags: probability, expected-value

Question: A wireless transmission system has bit error p bits per sec (0 < p < 1) and packet length n bits. What is the probability that a packet has an error?

Answer: 1 - (1-p)^n

I'm not sure how to get this answer for this practice problem. Wouldn't the probability just be p^n?

Comment: Nope.  $(1 - p)^n$ is the probability there is *no* bit error.  Then 1 minus that number gives the probability (or rate) that there *is* an error.  See?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p^n$ is the probability that *all of* the $n$ bits are in error.

Likewise, $(1-p)^n$ is the probability that *all of* them are error free.

You seek the probability that *at least one* among them are in error.

That is the probability that *not all of* them are error free.

So we use the rule of complements.

$$1-(1-p)^n$$